# JBoss: including subdirectories in Module Path

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using `JBoss EAP 6.4`. I have a modules folder that contains resources (configuration files needed by my application) and has the following file structure:

```
modules
    |
    |---resources
            |
            |---main
                |
                |---templates
                |       |---template1.xml
                |       |---template2.xml
                |
                |---axis2.xml
                |---hibernate.cfg.xml
                |---module.xml
```

My `module.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="resources">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
        <resource-root path="./templates"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

I also have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="resources" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I put the modules folder in `JBOSS_MODULEPATH`. The application can find the XML files in `modules/resources/main` like `axis2.xml` and `hibernate.cfg.xml`. However, it can't find the files in the subdirectory `templates` like `template1.xml`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm trying a similar config and encountered the same issues you're describing. My guess is that the JBoss classloader doesn't traverse subpaths in these custom modules. If it can work, I'd love to know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. When starting up the JBoss server I use the following startup parameter:

```
-Dresource.path=/path/to/modules/resources/main
```

So `resource.path` stays as an Environment property and I can access the files in the templates folder in this manner:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("resource.path") + "/templates/template1.xml");
```

Comment: I'm probably going to need to use an approach like this as well. It should be noted that this "workaround" foregoes the use of the JBoss module feature entirely, just referring to file resources by path.